# Hive queries run from edge nodes

Tags: hadoop, hive

Are there any disadvantages running hive `insert` queries from edge node against running it from oozie workflows?

Oozie docs says that running through oozie will distribute the workload to datanodes which are available.

But I was thinking running through edge node should still call job tracker and run in on cluster?

Answer (score 1):

When you run a Hive command from the edge node, it takes that command, creates machine-generated MapReduce code (in most cases), and sends that over to the cluster, where it is treated like any MapReduce job using as many data nodes as needed.  Oozie would do the same thing.  Either way.

So your assumption there is correct.